# Why does jQuery's .animate() run the "complete" function before it completes the animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm seeing this asked several places but most either give a work-around or the person's code doesn't prove the point.  I'm not really planning on scrolling down every pixel at 1 milisecond per pixel using jQuery .annimate(), but just to demonstrate the problem, here's my code:

```
window.stopscrolling = 0;

function scrollMore(id) {
   stopscrolling++;
   if (stopscrolling < 100) {
      var y = $(window).scrollTop();
      if ($("#"+id).offset().top != y){
         //console.log(y);
         if ($("#"+id).offset().top > y) {
             $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: y+1
             }, 1, "linear", function(){scrollMore(id);});
         }
         else {
             $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: y-1
             }, 1, "linear", function(){scrollMore(id);});
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you copy and paste it into the Chrome console, and run it like so: scrollMore("#itemId"), the window will only scroll down about 5 pixel, whilst it should scroll down 100.

Uncommenting the console.log will reveal that it runs through like this: pixel 0 once, pixel 1 four times, 2 eight times, 3 sixteen times, four 32 times, five 37 times; totaling 98 times.

I also tried with this syntax in the if, and it gave me the same results:

```
if ($("#"+id).offset().top > y) {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: y+1
     },
     {
        duration : 1,
        easing: "linear",
        complete: function(){scrollMore(id)}
    });
 }
```

I realise that I can use the following code to scroll to an item by ID, but my item moves on scroll, so it ends up scrolling to the wrong place.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top
    }, 2000);
```

So the question is, Why does jQuery run the "complete" function BEFORE it completes the animation when the documentation explicitly states that it runs after?  And, of course, what can I do about it?

Comment: It may have to do with this: "If multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole."

Comment: With a duration of 1, you might as well not even use .animate. By removing it, you'll see the issue has nothing to do with .animate.

Comment: Is this more along the lines of what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/rWNuR/1/

Comment: @DerekS Where did you find that?  Also, I'm only animating one element, $('html, body'), unless I misunderstood something?  Is there a work-around to make it execute for the animation as a whole?

Comment: @KevinB I know, and mentionned that in my post.  But set it to 10 ms or 100 ms, you'll have exactly the same effect.  On the contrary, if I remove the annimate the issue is gone: 

   if ($("#"+id).offset().top > y) {
       $('html, body').scrollTop(y+1);
       scrollMore(id);
   }

Comment: When i remove the animate it does nothing, just like when it's still there.

Comment: Also, `html,body` are two elements in some browsers, and one in others (for the purpose of this example anyway. They're actually two elements in all browsers). Therefore you will get inconsistent results using `html,body`

Comment: @Jonathan It's from the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: @KevinB your jsfiddle worked for what I was trying to do.  It didn't answer the question, but it solved my problem.

Comment: @DerekS - Thanks.  I guess that's the answer to the question.  I don't really understand why.  I'll try to look into it for better understanding.  Thank you!

Comment: @Jonathan I'm having a hard time believing that the complete callback is actually firing early. If you're asking why it is being called early, my answer would be it isn't being called early, something else entirely is happening.

Comment: @KevinB Turns out you're right.  As Chris Dolphin pointed out in the answer, my question was wrong.  I should have experimented more before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem a few weeks ago. When you try to animate multiple elements using syntax like `$('html, body').animate();` jQuery actually fires the animate function for both elements separately. Meaning that the callback parameter you added, `function(){scrollMore(id)}`, is actually called twice. That means when `html` is done animating it'll fire off it's callback before the `body`'s animation is even finished and then the `body`'s callback will fire as well once it's done its thing. I believe that's where those multiple unexpected console logs are coming from.

There's several ways to get around this but I'd say the easiest is to create a variable that tells the callbacks whether one has been fired or not. Something like:

```
var animated = false;

$('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: y+1
    },
    {
       duration : 1,
       easing: "linear",
       complete: function(){

          if (!animated) {
              animated = true;
              scrollMore(id);
          }

       }
    }
);
```

Comment: Or, you could use deferred objects. `.animate(options).promise().done(function(){ scrollMore(id); });`

Comment: @ChrisDolphin - There's the answer I was looking for!  animate() wasn't running early, it was running twice because of my $("html, body").  I should have experimented with that.  It also answers why I should be getting my console.log on squares of 2.  Great job, and thank you!